# ¿Como separar un documento PDF en multiples imagenes? (Según hojas del PDF) C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Comunidad StackOverflow:

Me gustaría solicitar su ayuda en cuanto a la separación de un documento PDF en varias imágenes con el lenguaje C#.

La idea es:

1. Recibir el PDF por un formulario web
2. Guardar dicho PDF en una carpeta local
3. **Procesar dicho PDF para separarlo en múltiples imágenes (dependiendo de la cantidad de hojas del PDF)**
4. Procesar cada imagen con Google AI Vision (*Ya está implementado y funcionando, solo debo pasarle las imágenes de la etapa 3*)

He probado con múltiples librerías para hacer este trabajo, pero la mayor parte de ellos son de pago. La única que me entrega resultados correctos, es una librería llamada ApiTron.PDF pero me deja una hermosa marca de agua en cada imagen, lo cual me hace imposible el trabajo final de procesar la imagen con Google AI Vision.

Les adjunto el codigo con el que recibo, guardo y proceso la imagen con dicha librería, para que entiendan la lógica, pero debo ocupar una librería que no sea de pago.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LoadFile(HttpPostedFileBase fileUpload)
    {
        string respuesta = "";
        string idGuia = "";
        if (fileUpload == null || fileUpload.ContentLength == 0)
        {
            ViewBag.Result = true;
            respuesta = "File not Found";
        }
        try
        {

            string dir = Server.MapPath("~/GD/");
            if (!Directory.Exists(dir)) {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
            }
            respuesta = dir + Path.GetFileName(fileUpload.FileName);
            //GUARDANDO PDF
            fileUpload.SaveAs(dir + Path.GetFileName(fileUpload.FileName));
        }

        catch (Exception e){
            return Json(new {Value = false, Message = e.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }


        string dirtemp;
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(respuesta, FileMode.Open))
        {
            // LEYENDO PDF ALMACENADO RECIENTEMENTE
            Document document = new Document(fs);


            RenderingSettings settings = new RenderingSettings();


            for (int i = 0; i < document.Pages.Count; i++)
            {
                Apitron.PDF.Rasterizer.Page currentPage = document.Pages[i];
                string dir = Server.MapPath("~/GD/");

                using (Bitmap bitmap = currentPage.Render((int)currentPage.Width, (int)currentPage.Height, settings))
                {
                    dirtemp = string.Format("{0}.png", i);
                    bitmap.Save(dir + Path.GetFileName(dirtemp));

                }
            }

        }

       //Procesamiento de imagen con Google Vision


        var client = ImageAnnotatorClient.Create();
        var image = Image.FromFile(respuesta);
        var response = client.DetectText(image);

        foreach (var annotation in response)
        {
            if (annotation.Description != null)
            {
                idGuia = idGuia + annotation.Description;
            }
        }

        var inicio = IndexOfWord(response.ToString(), "Aridos") + 11;
        idGuia = response.ToString().Substring(inicio, 5);
        return Json(new { Value = false, Message =  respuesta, NumeroGuia = idGuia}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Si tienen algún dato de librería que no sea de pago para hacer esto, lo agradecería un montón.

Comment: off-topic: ¿Qué contienen esos archivos PDF? ¿Imágenes escaneadas? ¿Quieres pasarle un ORC para extraer texto? ¿Qué tienes en mente?

Comment: Hola, tienen documentos escaneados a los cuales les paso la api de google Vision para obtener el codigo de cada documento. La idea de fondo es guardar cada documento como imagen (entiendase como documento, a cada hoja del PDF), para luego visualizarla en un buscador aparte.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres código de cada documento? ¿Texto?

Comment: Antes que se torne un chat, mejor vamos a la sala oficial: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instala esta librería PdfSharp, de preferencia una versión estable:

```
Install-Package PdfSharp -Version 1.50.5147
```

Recuerda incluir:

```
using PdfSharp;
using PdfSharp.Drawing;
using PdfSharp.Pdf;
using PdfSharp.Pdf.IO;
```

Ahora, un ejemplo:

```
// Aqui defines nombre del documento y su ruta
const string filename = "Portable Document Format.pdf";
File.Copy(Path.Combine("../../../../../PDFs/", filename), 
  Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), filename), true);

// Abre el documento
PdfDocument inputDocument = PdfReader.Open(filename, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);

string name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename);
for (int idx = 0; idx < inputDocument.PageCount; idx++)
{
  // Creas nuevo documento
  PdfDocument outputDocument = new PdfDocument();
  outputDocument.Version = inputDocument.Version;
  outputDocument.Info.Title =
    String.Format("Page {0} of {1}", idx + 1, inputDocument.Info.Title);
  outputDocument.Info.Creator = inputDocument.Info.Creator;

  // Agregas la página y la guardas
  outputDocument.AddPage(inputDocument.Pages[idx]);
  outputDocument.Save(String.Format("{0} - Page {1}_tempfile.pdf", name, idx + 1));
}
```

Ahora bien, para exportar cada página como imagen, revisa la documentación:

http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/ExportImages-sample.ashx

Alternativa a tu escenario: Usar Tesseract para .net, mira el siguiente enlace:

https://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_graphics/screencaptures/extracting-text-from-an-image-using-tesseract-in-c.html